# show text that is wider than the container, problems scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list elements that have no-wrap. These are inside a list that is in a fixed-size div with `overflow:hidden;overflow-y:auto` so that it is able to scroll. Text is cropped to the right as you would expect.

I am trying to show the "long" version of text that overflows a div as you mouse over. This relies pretty much on

```
if (0 > e.target.clientWidth - e.target.scrollWidth) {
```

(where `e.target` is the `LI` in a mouseover event).

Here's the basic principal working like I want (warning: ugly hack, improvements welcomed).

http://jsfiddle.net/h3yzhby0/

However, I'm stuck with scrolling. When I mouse over the element, it's added to the body since that is higher in z-order than the wrapper div (it's after it in dom and has a position:fixed) - it appears above the scrollbar for the div, as I need. When the mouse is over this element, I want the mouse wheel [and keyboard arrows which I haven't yet coded] to continue to scroll the div up and down. The event doesn't "bubble" from the mouse-over div because it's not of the same parent / node (and can't be, because of the overflow requirement).

Is there a way to pass or re-trigger the mousewheel event on a specific object (e.g. pass the event) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to add [`"pointer-events": "none"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to the long-version element, so the scrolling would not take it into account.

Then you'll need to check which elements needs the long-version, and add/remove additional `div.long-version` on mouseenter/mouseleave.

Comment: Ok that seems to make sense. And hiding the new element can be dealt with by examining the `scroll` event of the scrollable container. http://jsfiddle.net/h3yzhby0/5/